# Sharing a single sprinkler system zone wire?

Tags: schematics

Trying to share a five wire sprinkler system run to control five valves. I need a common wire, so now I have 4 valves. These are 24vac valves. I know this is possible because I have seen commercial products that are $50-$150.
(WireSprout, Doubler). That product has no requirement for power supplies and simply inserts on both ends of the wire run.

Seems To me there must be a simple circuit that does this and if it were DC valves it would just be two diodes at each end. Any ideas how the commercial product does this?
I wish to recreate it...

Thanks for the suggestions below.

Option #1: The diode approach seems most straight forward, but as jsotola said, the values may become magetized since they would be getting half-rectified AC rather than a full wave AC feed. I am not even sure if a sprinkler valve would operate with half rectified AC.

Option #2: The dual valve in parrallel approach suggested by vu2nan is straight forward, but runs the risk of reducing the actual water pressure too much. That said, if I reconfig my zones properly, I may be able to find the two zones that require the least amount of water pressure so when operated combined, would work fine. Interesting approach, and worth a try.

Option #3: Separately I heard from someone that suggested installing an ALTERNATING RELAY (something like the Macromatic Alternating Relay ARP024A3R) which would alternate which load gets power each time it is energized. I would simply have to remember that the zone alternates when I make my schedule and essentially turn the same zone on twice, once for loadA and then again for loadB.

I am thinking that the commercial WireSprout product is just the diode-only circuit shown above (not based on the HOLMAN AU patent above). $59 for a few diodes seems steep. I was not able to find a commercial product version of the HOLMAN patented approach. The 'Doubler' product is likely (based on the patent mentioned) the scenerio in Option #3, and for $150 seems to be a big markup for a $60 alternating relay.

I may try option #2 first. Its simple and may just work without extra 'stuff'. Will report back once running.

Thanks all.

Comment: What's the logic (ignoring the potential lack of wires). what devices need to be on and what need to be off - all possible states need to be considered. I don't know about sprinkler systems so you need to spell it out what you want the logic to be. Then comes the EE bit of working out how it can be done using 5 wires.

Comment: Patents are good for finding out how black boxes work. For example you may be interested in the following: https://patents.google.com/patent/US9786422B2/en

Comment: "the doubler" is a ratchet relay in a box.  the first signal activates one zone the second activates the other zone.

Comment: this is the patent called out in the doubler manual: https://patents.google.com/patent/US4575004A/en

Comment: Jasen, good find on the patent too. The description confirms it is an alternating relay: "A bistable electrical latching relay which when successively energized, switches energizing power to one of two or more conductive paths is housed in a waterproof casing and installed near an existing control valve ... Each time the relay is energized it alternately selects and energizes contacts. One set of contacts is wired to the existing valve and the other contacts are wired to one or more new valves."

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may work.

There may be a problem with the valve solenoids getting magnetized.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgVrrq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here's a compromise solution (connecting two valves in parallel).

[image]